# Get all values from JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hi would anyone help me how to get all value "clickUrl",
 I'm using file_get_content function and i want to wrap it in html

```html
<?php 
$json_url = "someone.web.id";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json=str_replace('},]',"}]",$json);
$data = json_decode($json);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

My Result is

```html
stdClass Object
(
    [serialId] => 110153837
    [productId] => 212065382
    [os] => Linux
    [validResponse] => 1
    [errorMessage] => 
    [adsDetails] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [requestTimestamp] => 1429665317403
                    [adId] => SAP_272131
                    [clickUrl] => http://adtrack.king.com
                 )
             [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [requestTimestamp] => 1429679659674
                    [adId] => SAP_182149
                    [clickUrl] => market://details?id    
                 )
             [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [requestTimestamp] => 1429679659674
                    [adId] => SAP_552219
                    [clickUrl] => http://t.mobitrk.com
                )   
            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [requestTimestamp] => 1429679659674
                    [adId] => SAP_562515
                    [clickUrl] => https://app.adjust.io
                )
        )
)
```

I dont know why my early posting deleted by meagar

Comment: You can pass second param as `true` to `json_decode($json, true);` so you will get associative array, than it's easier to manipulate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from stdobject to array and loops around it.

To receive JSON as array, just change this:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

to This:

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);
```

Then, loop around...

```
foreach ($data['adsDetails'] as $innerArray) {
   echo $innerArray['requestTimestamp'].'<br>';
   echo $innerArray['adId'].'<br>';
   echo $innerArray['clickUrl'].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to your info, you could get an array by:

```
$clickUrls = array_map(function($val) {
  return $val->clickUrl;
}, $data->adsDetails);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but where i can put that code (i'm newbie so sorry if my question is so stupid )